# Storyboard - Switch between 2 levels

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have the following simple Storyboard for an app. All I wanted to do is to go from Sub 1 screen to Sub 2 directly and vice versa. Do I really need to go to Main Screen to achieve this?

What is the "Replace" segue? Or is there any other thing I can do to achieve this?

(unfortunately, I can't post a picture)

Navigation Controller -> Main View Controller -> "Sub 1" View Controller
                                              -> "Sub 2" View Controller

On both Sub1 & Sub2, I have buttons to segue to both.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding the question correctly, but why not use a modal segue?

Make a new iPhone app in xcode and select Utility app to see a pre-made example.

Comment: If you consider Main Screen as the View Controller and do a model segue for Sub1 or Sub2, it will be find. But if I try to go from Sub1 to Sub2 directly, how will I do it? It's very easy if I can show the image.

Image: http://db.tt/FQ1Hlfr1